# Show Custom Task Pane on other (already opened) Custom Task Pane in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have two Custom Task Panes as below,

1. Custom Task Pane One: CTP_1
2. Custom Task Pane Two: CTP_2

When I click button (of CTP_1), click event should open CTP_2 over CTP_1 in Outlook AddIn 2010.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what you mean by

> open CTP_2 over CTP_1

If you mean literally open one docked Task Pane window over the top of another Task Pane window in Outlook; you can't.

You could possibility do it if 1 or both were floating task pane windows. But you wouldn't be able to keep them in position when the Outlook Explorer / Inspector window was moved and/or resized. So I wouldn't recommend this idea.

If you wanted to replace CTP_1 with CTP_2 when you click a button you could:

- Hide CTP_1 when the button is clicked and then display CTP_2
- Or if you want to stop it flickering when hidding a custom task and displaying another, create another usercontrol that contained both CTP_1 and CTP_2 and set their Visibility accordingly when the button is clicked

You can get a reference to added Custom Task Panes using the `ThisAddin.CustomTaskPanes` property.

Or you can dock them next to each other by setting the `CustomTaskPane.DockPosition` property (of each CustomTaskPane) to same value.
i.e.

```
CTP_1.DockPosition = MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
CTP_2.DockPosition = MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
```